# Azure graph API / c# patch URL

Tags: c#, azure, graph, passwords

I am attempting to write a password reset application c# and the graph API. I have set permissions for the application within Azure, receive a valid token,  and can request information.

I am receiving a 400 Bad Request response when attempting to perform the reset.  I believe I am forming the URL incorrectly.  Here is the response I receive followed by my code.

Thanks in advance!

```
Response: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  request-id: omitted
  client-request-id: omitted
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceA","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_29","ADSiteName":"CHI"}}
  Duration: 43.0949
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Mon, 02 Apr 2018 18:06:06 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
}

private static async Task ResetPasswordAsync(HttpClient client, string UPN)
    {
        var payload = new
        {
            accountEnabled = true,
            passwordProfile = new
            {
                forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                password = "Password!"
            }
        };
        var payloadJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
        Console.WriteLine(payloadJSON);
        HttpMethod method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        string requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UPN}?api-version=1.6";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUrl)
        {
            Content = new StringContent($"{payloadJSON}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `400 Bad Request`, we could know that there is something wrong with http request. In your case, you could use Fiddler to catch the htt prequest, we could get `Query parameter api-version not allowed`. So you could remove the api version from the requesturl.

[image]

We could get more information about update use from Graph [Update user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update) API

```
PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

We also need to add the Authorization in the request header.

```
string requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UPN}";
var token ="Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFCSGg0...."
...
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```